# Android: cyanogenmod set wifi hotspot channel or frequency

Tags: android, android-wifi, cyanogenmod

I have rooted phone (HTC One, Android 4.4.4) with cyanogenmod and in my app I create Acces Point:

```
        Method method = mWifiManager.getClass().getMethod(
                "setWifiApEnabled", WifiConfiguration.class, boolean.class);

        Boolean suc = (Boolean) method.invoke(mWifiManager, wifiConfig,
                enabled);
```

It´s ok but AP is always created at the channel 6 and I want change this channel. I tried a lot of different codes, but nothing work. This should work:

```
        Field fFreq = WifiConfiguration.class.getField("frequency");
        int freq = 2412; // default to channel 1
        fFreq.setInt(wifiConfig, freq);
```

from http://www.thinktube.com/tech/android/wifi-ibss but the channel is still 6. Do you know what is wrong? What should I set or change?

Thanks!